# Create httphandler for requests with NO file extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I want to create an HttpHandler that is called only for page requests (not css, scripts, images, etc) in my MVC application.

How do I target requests with no extension only in the web.config file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IIS7 then this should be handled automatically, without having to create a HttpHandler